# Installing aiohttp on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, httprequest

I want to install the `aiohttp` package on heroku.
But I've got the following:

```
Collecting aiohttp
  Using cached aiohttp-3.1.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting yarl<2.0,>=1.0 (from aiohttp)
  Using cached yarl-1.1.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting multidict<5.0,>=4.0 (from aiohttp)
  Using cached multidict-4.1.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting async-timeout<3.0,>=1.2 (from aiohttp)
  Using cached async_timeout-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting idna-ssl>=1.0 (from aiohttp)
  Using cached idna-ssl-1.0.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'tests_require'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'install_requires'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'python_requires'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'include_package_data'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'zip_safe'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
       or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
       or: -c --help-commands
       or: -c cmd --help

    error: invalid command 'egg_info'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-uyayoban/idna-ssl/
```

The same thing occurred when I have tried to install grequests instead.
So how can I install one of this packages on heroku, or are there other ways to make async http requests from heroku?